# PHP Fatal Error: Cannot use object of type DataAccess as array

Tags: php, constructor, data-access

I cannot figure out why I am getting the following error in PHP:

*Fatal error: Cannot use object of type DataAccess as array in /filename on line 16.*

Here is the relevant code for the file:

```
class StandardContext implements IStandardContext
{
    private $dataAccess;

    // (CON|DE)STRUCTORS
    function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->dataAccess = new DataAccess($config['db']); //this is line 16
    }
```

$config refers to the following:

```
$config = require(dirname(__FILE__)./*truncated*/.'Config.php');
```

Here is the relevant code for Config.php:

```
return array(

    // Database connection parameters
    'db' => array(
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'name' => 'visum',
        'user' => 'root',
        'password' => ''
    )
);
```

Here is the relevant code for the DataAccess object:

```
class DataAccess
{
    private $link;
    private $db;

    function __construct($dbConfig)
    {            
        $this->link = mysql_connect( $dbConfig['host'], $dbConfig['user'], $dbConfig['password'] ) or die(mysql_error());
        $this->db = $dbConfig['name'];
        mysql_select_db($this->db) or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciate, I am fairly new to PHP and am absolutely stumped.

Edit: BTW, I have included the following code to test StandardContext, which actually works (ie. it allows me to make changes to my database farther down than I have shown)

```
class StandardContext_index_returns_defined_list implements ITest
{
    private $dataAccess;

    function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->dataAccess = new DataAccess($config['db']);
    }
```

Comment: Doh, made a stupid comment and my stupid iPhone won't let me delete it :)

Comment: Did you do a `var_dump($config['db']);` before instantiating DataAccess object to ensure it is indeed an array? Looking at your code it appears to be ok. The only other thing that is missing is the function wrapper around the `return array` in your Config.php, would be nice to see that for a complete picture.

Comment: Strangely, when I replace line 16 with 'var_dump($config['db']);' I continue to get the exact same error message.

Comment: Also, the only code I did not show on Config.php are the <?php tags.  Am I missing something to tie it all together? Sorry, I am new to not only PHP, but programming as well.

Comment: What about `var_dump($config)`?

Comment: var_dump($config) worked, it gave me the following output: **object(DataAccess)#2 (2) { ["link":"DataAccess":private]=> resource(11) of type (mysql link) ["db":"DataAccess":private]=> string(5) "visum" }**

Comment: So your problem is that `$config` already is a `DataAccess` object, not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost like you are trying to use a singleton pattern, but for every StandardContext object you instantiate, you are passing in database parameters (via $config array). I think what's happening is that you are passing the $config array more than once, after the first pass the $config is no longer an array, but an instance of the DataAccess class, which is why you are getting that error. You can try the following:

```
class StandardContext implements IStandardContext
{
    private $dataAccess;

    // (CON|DE)STRUCTORS
    function __construct($config)
    {
        if ($config instanceof DataAccess) {
            $this->dataAccess = $config;
        } elseif ((is_array($config)) && (array_key_exists('db', $config))) {
            $this->dataAccess = new DataAccess($config['db']); 
        } else {
            throw new Exception('Unable to initialize $this->dataAccess');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is problem with your

```
private $dataAccess;
```

check the array object here

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php

whenever you declare outside a method inside class, it will consider as Object , so you have to declare inside method or declare as method itself else remove implements from your class.

your $dataAccess is an Object , because you declare it outside the method and your new DataAccess($config['db']) will return an arrayObject because you implements that, so it is trying to convert from Object to arrayObject leads an error

Comment: That link is a little terse.  Do you mean that because $dataAccess is an array, it must be declared inside a method or else the array will be converted to an object, leading to this error?

Comment: @Indy $dataAccess is an Object , because you declare it outside the method and your new DataAccess($config['db']) will return an arrayObject because you implements that, so it is trying to convert from Object to arrayObject leads an error

Comment: That make some sense, but I do not see where I implement arrayObject. I thought you had to explicitly declare it (ie new ArrayObject(); ).  The reason I am so hesitant to accept this is because I have basically the same code for my test, and it works.  Please see the EDIT on the original post.  Thanks for your patience Robin.